# Set ImageView SRC Programmatically Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am using [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) to make an circular image, but I want to overlay a picture overtop of this. Sicne setting `CircleImageView` backgroundColor gets rid of the circle (Fill it as a square) I have a regular image view and put it over top of `CircleImageView` and set the regular image view `.setImageDrawable` to the picture I want. But I need to set the src of the `CircleImageView` programtically as a color which I currently have as and int. So I am wondering how I can set the `CircleImageView` src programaticlly as a color?

I tried `backgroundImage.setBackgroundResource(colorAsInt);`

but this gave ERROR: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff7f0106`

Thanks

Comment: try backgroundImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 100));

Comment: @JRowan I can't set backgroundColor as it remove the circle from the `CircleImageView` and just fills the whole background

Comment: Try `backgroundImageImageView.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(colorAsInt));`, Not sure if it'll work; I've not used that library.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks if you want to post as answer for +1

Comment: did you try setFillColor method that comes with CircleImageView, maybe that will work

Comment: @JRowan That's a good idea, but looking at the source, I don't think it'll work as expected. The image would need to be completely transparent - in which case we'd have to set a `ColorDrawable` anyway - or null - but if it's null, `onDraw()` returns without doing anything. @spenf10 I'll post an answer shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since setting the background color defeats the View's intended functionality, it seems the only option is to set the source image. Using a `ColorDrawable` of the desired color should work.

```
backgroundImageImageView.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(colorAsInt));
```